# xpathFactory issue in Multithreaded java application

Tags: java, multithreading, xpath, thread-local

I have xpathutility class that i use throughout my application to get String or node results from xpath expression :

```
public static String getStringResult(String expression, Document doc) {
        String outString = new String();

        try {
            outString = (String)xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        return outString;
    }
    public static NodeList getNodeListResult(String expression, Document doc) {
        NodeList outList = null;

        try {
            outList = (NodeList)xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        return outList;
    }
```

For initialization of factory i have used the following, to make thread safe, found it over internet:

```
 private static final ThreadLocal<XPathFactory> XPATH_FACTORY = new ThreadLocal<XPathFactory>()
    {
        @Override
        protected XPathFactory initialValue()
        {
            return XPathFactory.newInstance();
        }
    };
    private static final XPath xpath= XPATH_FACTORY.get().newXPath();
```

But when i execute this from multiple threads it give me null pointer expection for xpath. Need to know how to make it thread safe.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but do be aware that DOM is not thread-safe. With the Apache / JDK DOM implementation, you can't even assume it's thread-safe for read-only operations.

Comment: I think you need to post some more code. For example a [mre]. Then we will be (more probably at least) be able to see what's wrong. Where are you getting the `NullPointerException`? Are you sure it's `xpath` variable which is `null` or is the `expression` variable `null`?